# How to send a file to a server

Tags: c++

I want to make a program such that the user runs the client program and then writes the name of a file to be transferred to the server, the user should be able to set the server address. Then the server accepts the file and saves it to its working directory with the same name.

I don't know how to do this.

This is my code:

Server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData)) {
        cout << "Error\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port        = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

    SOCKET newConnection;
    newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &sizeofaddr);

    if (newConnection == 0) cout << "Error #2\n";
    else                cout << "Client connected!\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData)) {
        cout << "Error\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port        = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        cout << "Error: failed connect to server\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Connected!\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are asking a lot of question at one time, and we are not here to just write the code for you, or give you tutorials. Do you know how to read in user input?  How to create/open a file, and read from/write to the file?  The code you have shown is not doing any of that. Start with the basics first, before you add socket I/O and protocol design on top of that, which will have its own complexities for you to deal with. Take things one step at a time, and master each skill before moving on to the next one.

Comment: hi I know working with a file is simple I do not know how to send a file to a serve

Comment: What has your research taught you? What have you attempted? Clearly you have been reading up about this, since you already know about `WSAStartup()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, `connect()`, and `accept()`. Now you need to add `recv()` to the server, and `send()` to the client. The rest deals with HOW you send the filename and data from the client and receive it on the server. The client opens a file, `send()` the filename, and `send()` what is read from the file. The server `recv()` the filename, creates the file, and writes what is `recv()` to the file. There are plenty of tutorials about that.

Comment: Thank you very much for sending a file. Which one is better than TCP or UDP?
I'm simple the first time I do it

Comment: Either TCP or UDP can be used, one is not "better" than the other. It depends on the protocol you decide to use with either one. That said, for a beginner, TCP will probably be simpler to learn, since it provides more guarantees implicitly that UDP simply does not, in particular TCP guarantees data is delivered (baring a connection failure), and in the same order that it was sent. UDP doesn't provide those guarantees, so UDP based protocols have to account for that explicitly in their design.

Comment: thank you very much